# Having the same printer installed two times with different configurations

Tags: windows, printer

We have a networked laser printer at work which we use for two different tasks. One of them needs high quality printing, and for the other we prefer to use the lowest quality available, mainly for toner saving.

Is a PITA to change between the two configurations every time we print, so... Is it possible to install the same printer two times at the same time, for example one with name and configuration "High quality", and the other "Low quality", and send the jobs to one or another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it's a PITA or not. That is relative to the person doing the configuring. If adding configurations saves you time in the long run, it's not a PITA.

Here is what you do; use the **Add Printer** function and choose to add the same printer again (*it may ask for drivers, so be ready*). Do this for each configuration you want. Name them as you said with descriptive names so they are easy to identify.

Once installed, change the configuration as you need. You can then select the configuration you want when you use the print dialog.

Comment: Please excuse me, it seems I didn't explained myself correctly. What I'm asking is exactly how to do what you say, I'm on Windows XP and it doesn't allow me to add the same printer again.

Comment: It might be a good idea for you to [edit] your question by adding those details. Anyone who is trying to answer your question is only able to use what information you give them. If it is not specific, you will get a non-specific answer.

Comment: I have installed multiple copies of the same printer on XP before. So, there must be some restriction which is stopping you, like a group policy or profile restriction. Do you have administrator privileges? As far as `step by step` instructions, [here are some](http://www.ehow.com/how_7542607_add-copies-printer-different-settings.html) for you.

Comment: Ok, the problem was the printer being connected to another computer and I trying to connect to it more than one time. You can do it locally, so your answer is correct even if it doesn't help me :(. One point for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to add the same printer multiple times; and no, it is not a pain--in fact, it's a lot more convenient than having to remember to change the settings every time.  The only part that's annoying is that, if you have many printers that you print to, the printer list can get pretty cluttered.

For example, I have the following printers, all of which print to the same physical printer, but with different settings:

- Dell 3110cn
- Dell 3110cn Duplex
- Dell 3110cn 2up

You can set up multiple copies of the printer via the "Add a Printer" control panel applet, or by running the printer's setup program again.  If you use the "Add a Printer" applet, you can tell it to use the driver that's already installed.  Once you have multiple copies installed, click the `Start` menu/Windows button, then `Devices and Printers`.  Right-click on the printer and select `Properties`, then configure the settings as you wish and customize the name as appropriate.